# moment to date object timezone issue

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have a moment.js object generated from fullcalendar in BST that looks like this:

```
console.log(momentSelected)
//Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: true, _offset: 0, _locale: f, _d: Tue May 03 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)…}
```

I don't want a BST time but a UTC time that looks like this:

```
console.log(momentSelected.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z'));
//2016-05-03 00:00 +00:00
```

Now I need to convert it into a Date object:

```
$scope.date = new Date(momentSelected.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z'));
console.log($scope.date);
//Wed May 04 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

The last output is wrong... I want `Wed May 04 2016 00:00:00+00:00 (UTC)`

Comment: But it shows that `_isUTC: true, _offset: 0` is already in UTC. Maybe you need to use [Date.prototype.toUTCString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

Comment: yes I agree so why does it create a Date object in BST...

Comment: @Matt's answer explains it ( _If your local time zone is UK (alternating between GMT and BST for daylight saving time), then it is impossible to get (UTC) time in the string produced by console.log($scope.date);, regardless of how you created that date_ )

Comment: Also, `console.log` trigger the `.toString()` prototype of the date object that print the date in your local timezone (http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/using-javascripts-tostring-method)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `Date` object using the `toDate` function on the moment object.

```
$scope.date = momentSelected.toDate();
```

However, you must recognize that the nature of the `Date` object is that it will *always* represent UTC internally, and its `toString` function will *always* reflect the local time zone where the code is running.

If your local time zone is UK (alternating between GMT and BST for daylight saving time), then it is impossible to get `(UTC)` time in the string produced by `console.log($scope.date);`, regardless of how you created that date.

This is why it is better to use moment's `format` function and display that string directly.  A `moment` can reflect UTC, local time, and other time zones.  A `Date` object cannot.

Also, you should pay no attention to the underscore-prefixed internal fields of a `moment` object.  Use the public API instead.  See the [moment user guide](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/).

Comment: Finally I get it! How do I access the internally stored UTC time. Basically every date I have is using moment and is in UTC but for this one thing I must use I need a date object. So $scope.date is the date object now I need to convert is back to moment but the moment is off by one hour. So I need the opposite of the toDate() method.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `.utc()` and `.local()` functions.  You can then use `format` to produce your string however you like.  Really, when using moment.js, you should avoid using the `Date` object unless you you really need it, such as for interacting with other components that require one.

Comment: Tell me about it... The guy that created that object should be strung up!

Comment: Oh, if you want to get into history, you'll have to look to committees instead of one guy.  ;)   I could give a dissertation on the subject...